# Can't change the color of the sprinkles

Tags: node-editor, color, compositing-nodes

[image] [image]
following blinder guru in his tutorial for beginners i colored the sprinkles but then i wanted to change some colors but i couldn't .. when i go to the compositing mode, the nodes aren't the ones of the sprinkles although i made sure i select the sprinkles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Compositing and Material Editor are two node-based Editor Types that are very different. Beginners can get these mixed up.

The Compositing Workspace is to edit your final renders and do things like color correction, effects, and things like that.

The Material Editor is the actual Editor you want. This will actually let you change how the material is defined through tweaking nodes, and you can simply access it by changing the Editor to "Shader Editor", and selecting a sprinkle. If you want to change the colors, just go to the colorramp (the thing with a colorful bar) and change the colors by selecting flags.

Comment: oh thanks a lot .. i just figured this out and it worked :"d